# How to show fuzzy output result in label not in interger value?

Tags: matlab

I work on fuzzy in MATLAB and I make some rules with two shape features input (edge pixel count and minimum X axis). and use mamdani algorithm, and also define an output (my output has 4 trimf with separate labels). I export my fuzzy to my workspace and save it with DotFuzzy name.
I write DotFuzzy(23,29); to call my fuzzy set and wait for result. but show me error.

```
>> DotFuzzy(23,29)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

then I wrote this:

```
evalfis([23,29],DotFuzzy)

ans =

    0.2500
```

But I think it shows me the result that this number is contain. ( for example show the trim label instead of this number)
How can I show the result in class label not in number value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason. Fuzzy can not show the result in class label. It just show the output in numbers. But we can define the interval for each label in output and get the last result number and check it between the interval. For example if the result is 0.42 and in output this number belong to class label B (with this interval 0.30-0.50) so make structures and check the interval in your code and print B in output.